# how to find li with a particular data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu shopping-cart-nav-drpdown">                                                              
    <li class="item" data-item-id="58">

     </li>
     <li class="item" data-item-id="100">

     </li>
     <li class="item last">
     <a href="/cart" class="btn btn-info full-button">View Cart</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Inside this `shopping-cart-nav-drpdown`, how do I find the li that has data-item-id=58? Is it possible to do this without iterating through all the children of ul and use getAttributes?

Comment: `$("li[data-item-id=58]")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure:

```
 $("li[data-item-id=58]")
```

And an awesome [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BZPRy/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to do this without iterating through all the children of `ul`:

```
$('.shopping-cart-nav-drpdown li[data-item-id="58"]');
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/HyXcC/)

You can also make it dynamic like this:

```
var data = 58;
$('.shopping-cart-nav-drpdown li[data-item-id="' + data + '"]');
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/HyXcC/1/)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
jQuery( ".shopping-cart-nav-drpdown li" ).each(function(){
    if($(this).data('item-id')=="58"){
    alert('found');
    }
  });
```

Comment: From OP: `Is it possible to do this without iterating through all the children of ul and use getAttributes?`